# Append Div After 1st Paragraph For Each Article When More Than 1 Paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to append ( rather than use .after() ) a HTML div after the first paragraph of text for each article only when there's at least 2 paragraphs for each article, otherwise don't add the div?

```js
 $('.content').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.children('p').length >= 2) {  
      $this.append('<div id="toggle">Read More</div>');
      $('p').not('p:first-child').wrap('<div class="text" />');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
<p>This is an example of a paragraph</p>
<p>This is an example of a paragraph</p>
</div>

<div class="content">
<p>This is an example of a paragraph</p>
</div>

<div class="content">
<p>This is an example of a paragraph</p>
<p>This is an example of a paragraph</p>
<p>This is an example of a paragraph</p>
</div>
```

This is what i need to achieve. The divs are only added when there's more than 1 paragraph of text for each content div.

```
<div class="content">
<p>This is an example of a paragraph</p>
<div class="text" />
<p>This is an example of a paragraph</p>
<div id="toggle">Read More</div>
</div>

<div class="content">
<p>This is an example of a paragraph</p>
</div>

<div class="content">
<p>This is an example of a paragraph</p>
<div class="text" />
<p>This is an example of a paragraph</p>
<div id="toggle">Read More</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to wrap every paragraph after the first in a single div? If not, can you give us a second HTML example of what your desired effect is?

Comment: yes, see update. The Read More should only be added if there's more than 1 paragraph for each content div.

Comment: @Dev See my answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were so close!

```js
$('.content').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.children('p').length >= 2) {  
      $this.append('<div id="toggle">Read More</div>');
  }
});
```

```css
.content {
border:1px solid red;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

.content p {
margin:0;
}

.content #toggle {
margin-top:5px;
color:cyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
<p>This is an example of a paragraph</p>
<p>This is an example of a paragraph</p>
</div>

<div class="content">
<p>This is an example of a paragraph</p>
</div>

<div class="content">
<p>This is an example of a paragraph</p>
<p>This is an example of a paragraph</p>
<p>This is an example of a paragraph</p>
<p>This is an example of a paragraph</p>
</div>


<div class="content">
<p>This is an example of a paragraph</p>
</div>


<div class="content">
<p>This is an example of a paragraph</p>
<p>This is an example of a paragraph</p>
<p>This is an example of a paragraph</p>
<p>This is an example of a paragraph</p>
<p>This is an example of a paragraph</p>
<p>This is an example of a paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks good ProEvilz, let me test it locally with the rest of my code.

Comment: Ignore the CSS, it's just for visual purposes

Comment: Not quite there because it doesn't work when there's 3 paragraphs or more.

Comment: If the code I provide here works, then it *simply* **does work**... If when you put it into your own code and it doesn't work then your issue is that your code is breaking it somehow.

Comment: Agree however the problem is your solution doesn't wrap the 2nd and subsequent paragraphs in the text div which is needed for the toggle.

Comment: Add this after ProEvilz if{} block: `$this.children('p:not(:first-child)').wrapAll('<div class="text" />');`

Comment: Works. Thanks, but why use .wrapAll instead of .wrap?

Comment: .wrap() will execute once for each item in the collection (so if you have two or more paragraph tags, each one would have its own <div class="text"/> wrapper), while .wrapAll() accepts a collection and wraps one single element around them all, resulting in only one <div class="text"/> wrapper regardless of how many extra paragraphs you have. I presume you want the latter so you can show/hide them all at the same time when the user clicks read more.

Comment: Excellent. Learn't a lot from you. Is it better to use .append or .after?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to append ( rather than use .after() ) a HTML div after the first paragraph of text for each article only when there's at least 2 paragraphs for each article, otherwise don't add the div?

— Answer: Yes, it's possible.

***Note:*** Your `id="toggle"` is not unique, you may only have one unique ID per page, or you blow up the internet.

#### Example

```js
let $read = $('<div class="read">Read More</div>');
let $text = $('<div class="text"></div>');

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.content').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('p').length > 1;
  }).append($read.clone()).find('p:first').after($text.clone());

});
```

```css
.content {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.read {
  background: #eee;
  border-top: 1px solid #999;
  color: #369;
  text-align: center;
}

.text {
  background: #9c9;
  padding: .5rem;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
  <p>This is an example of a paragraph</p>
  <p>This is an example of a paragraph</p>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <p>This is an example of a paragraph</p>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <p>This is an example of a paragraph</p>
  <p>This is an example of a paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @Dev ignore CSS for style visualization

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: You don’t need to, you can use a *class* as depicted above. Mind you, this solution was used to illustrate the `filter` method.